# Get drive model from drive letter

Tags: c#

I want to get the model name from a drive letter. For example `Crucial_CT256MX100SSD1` is the model of my drive `C:\`

The model can be retrieved with a simple WMI query,

```
var hdd = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Index = '0'")
    .Get()
    .Cast<ManagementObject>()
    .First();
MessageBox.Show(hdd["Model"].ToString());
```

However, I cannot filter the query with the drive letter.

Unfortunately `Win32_LogicalDisk` doesn't have the model of the drive.

I don't have more ideas.

Comment: You still need to use WMI. I don't know the exact query, but you need to look at a _physical_ drive. A drive letter doesn't correspond to a specific physical drive. It may represent a partition within a single drive, the only partition on a single drive, or even a logical partition that spans multiple drives. So the first step is to decide what you really mean by "get the model name from a drive letter".

Comment: When reading your question another time, I think I have not given a correct answer to your question. But mabe this helps you further: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial233_Getting-Disk-Drive-Information-using-WMI-and-Csharp.html

Comment: @Sjips If you *know* you haven't given the correct answer, ***don't answer the question!***

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote you a function that should do what you need:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string drive = "C:";

        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}'s Model Number is {1}", drive, GetModelFromDrive(drive));
    }

    public static string GetModelFromDrive(string driveLetter)
    {
        // Must be 2 characters long.
        // Function expects "C:" or "D:" etc...
        if (driveLetter.Length != 2)
            return "";

        try
        {
            using (var partitions = new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" + driveLetter +
                                             "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskPartition"))
            {
                foreach (var partition in partitions.Get())
                {
                    using ( var drives = new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" +
                                                         partition["DeviceID"] +
                                                         "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskDrive"))
                    {
                        foreach (var drive in drives.Get())
                        {
                            return (string) drive["Model"];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return "<unknown>";
        }

        // Not Found
        return "<unknown>";
    }
}
```

Just pass in a string, such as `C:` or `D:`. It must be just the drive letter and a colon. Also, I made this work for just hard drives. It will not work on CD-ROM drives. It can be expanded, if you need that functionality though.

Comment: Works fine, even with USB flash drives or USB hard drives. Thanks !

Comment: This could be simplified by calling ManagementObject.GetRelated() which is the equivalent of ASSOCIATORS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the partition-drive mapping can be read from the `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition` and `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` classes.

Answer (score 1):

Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition, Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition

Brute force:

1. Take all disks

   SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive
2. For each disk get partitions

   ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=*disk.DeviceID* } WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition
3. For each partition get volume letter

   ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=*partition.DeviceID*} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the info from the registry. I have an Intel SSD, and I looked up its name in the device manager. When I did a registry search I found it:

[image]

So I think when you code to iterate trough the `HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi` you can find the info.

Comment: This only *partially* answers the question. Please edit your answer with a code example of HOW to retrieve this information, and I will remove the downvote and instead upvote.