# Obtaining HDD Serial Number via Drive Letter using WMI query in C#

Tags: c#, wmi, hard-drive

I have the following code which works well in obtaining HDD serial numbers via the Model string value in `Win32_DiskDrive`. But I need to obtain the serial number via the drive letter assigned. Is this possible? If so how?

```
public string GetDriveSerial(string model)
{
    string serial = string.Empty;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '" + model + "'";
    try
    {
        using (var results = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject result in results.Get())
            {
                serial = result["SerialNumber"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return serial;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public static string GetSerialFromDrive(string driveLetter)
{
    try
    {
        using (var partitions = new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" + driveLetter +
                                            "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskPartition"))
        {
            foreach (var partition in partitions.Get())
            {
                using (var drives = new ManagementObjectSearcher("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" +
                                                        partition["DeviceID"] +
                                                        "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskDrive"))
                {
                    foreach (var drive in drives.Get())
                    {
                        return (string)drive["SerialNumber"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return "<unknown>";
    }

    // Not Found
    return "<unknown>";
}
```

This expects the drive letter like this: "C:", "D:" ...
The original code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27629626/3455216).

Comment: That's good, however I may have two USB hard disks connected that are the same model. This would make it hard to obtain the correct serial no. via the model query in `Win32_DiskDrive`. I need to query the serial via drive letter.

Comment: @MickIlovski I updated my answer. Forgot, that the drive already holds the information about the serial number. So you only need one method.