# c++. How to get the serial number of a network drive?

Tags: c++, winapi

How to get the serial number of a computer's hard drive on a local network? For example, network disk "Z:" ("Network\\COMP1"). I want to bind my program to this serial number. I tried using the function that I used when getting the serial number of the local physical disk, but it didn't work.

```
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\Z:", 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

hDevice returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to go to the computer that has the drive on the local network, and use `wmic diskdrive get model,serialnumber` from CMD.

Comment: I doubt there's a way of doing this.  It simply won't be available via a network share.  To add to @eljay's comment, the `vol` command will also display it.

Comment: @Eljay The program will be located on a network drive (this option is better) or on the user's local computer. In any case, when it starts, it must obtain the serial number of the network drive and then compare it with the allowed one. So I still need a programmatic way to get the network drive's serial number. Or does the network license have a different logic?

Comment: @PaulSanders How then is the logic of network licenses implemented? Maybe there is another meaning?

Comment: _How then is the logic of network licenses implemented?_ What do you mean by 'network licenses'?  Can you give an example of one and what it enforces?

Comment: @PaulSanders 'network licenses' - The program is located on a shared network drive, to which all network users have access. When the user starts the program, it checks the serial number of the network drive and compares it with a valid one.

Comment: That's a strange licencing model anyways. It will favor companies which have network drives and it punishes single users who don't have a network drive

Comment: _When the user starts the program, it checks the serial number of the network drive and compares it with a valid one._ Do you know of any software that actually does this then?

Comment: If you need to license software, there are existing solutions you can just use. If you make your own it will get cracked in a weekend by the first person who cares to try.

Comment: @PaulSanders VetCad for AutoCad has such a "network" license. I'm just starting to explore the issue of licensing. Can you tell me what I can study on this issue?

Comment: @tadman I'm just starting to explore the issue of licensing. Can you tell me what I can study on this issue? Are there any free solutions you are talking about?

Comment: It depends *what* you're licensing and what level of threat you're dealing with. Banging together something yourself is just going to create misery for your end-users and cause lost sales. You should stick with some existing solution, of which there are many. You'll have to do your own research here to find what fits with *your specific needs*.

Comment: _VetCad for AutoCad has such a "network" license_ Sure, but you're assuming you know how it works.  _Can you tell me what I can study on this issue?_ Well, what I personally do is to issue license keys which my software then checks against my 'licensing server' (it's just a webserver, basically) so that I can revoke the license if someone misbehaves.  It's difficult to know exactly _how_ they're using the license though, and I don't want to reveal how I do that.

Comment: You could try to use `Win32_DiskDrive`. Refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628965/get-drive-model-from-drive-letter